# CGI::Session::Auth doesn't exist for Debian

Tags: perl, debian

I tried to install CGI::Session::Auth but it doesn't exist.

```
> dh-make-perl locate CGI::Session::Auth
== dh-make-perl 0.116 ==
Using cached Contents from Thu Jul 27 13:21:51 2023
CGI::Session::Auth is not found in any Debian package
```

Also it didn't work when I tried this:

```
> sudo apt-get install -y libcgi-session-auth-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcgi-session-auth-perl
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the reason it's not available as a Debian package is the security issues listed [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=67977)

Comment: Is there a substitute that I could use?

Comment: How do I give credit for your correct answer?

Comment: @MarcosCamargo on the left of the answer where you can vote there is a tick mark that you can click. Also consider taking the [tour] to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the module using `cpan CGI::Session::Auth`